# Comparison operators with a CASE statement and Window Function

Tags: sql, mysql, case, window-functions

I'm trying to use a case function with a window function, but the data I'm getting doesn't add up. Everything seems to work, but I'm only receiving "Above Average" for that entire CASE function, so I know something isn't quite right. I would love for each row to give an indication of whether those sales were above, below, or equal to that city's average.

I feel like it's a simple syntax thing, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Please help!

```
select 
    *,
case
    when total_sales > "City Average Total Sales" then "Above Average"
    when total_sales < "City Average Total Sales" then "Below Average"
    when total_sales = "City Average Total Sales" then "Equal to Average"
end as "Sales Tracking"
from (
    select 
        *,
        round(total_sales / Population, 0) AS "Revenue Over Residents",
        round(avg(total_sales) over (Partition by city), 2) as "City Average Total Sales"
    from nm_cannabis_sales_population) a;
```

Again, I'm getting the Above Average result for that entire column, and I'm using MySQL if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is largely accurate - all you need to do is use a backquote instead of the double-quotes for the column `City Average Total Sales`

The double-quotes are causing "City Average Total Sales" to be interpreted as a literal instead of a column name.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing a value (say "100") to the *string* "City Average Total Sales" (as opposed to the column named "City Average Total Sales".)

To fix the ambiguity, you can use backticks for the column name, like:

```
case
    when total_sales > `City Average Total Sales` then "Above Average"
    when total_sales < `City Average Total Sales` then "Below Average"
    when total_sales = `City Average Total Sales` then "Equal to Average"
end as "Sales Tracking"
```

You can see the problem and solution [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BL4uKTDO).

An alternate solution is to set [your sql mode to ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html). That way MySQL will treat the double quotes in your outer query the way that I think you are expecting (and the way most other DBMSes do).